# How to fix this output window mess when building?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, f#

When building any F# project in VS2010 this is what I see in the output window:

```
------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Release x86 ------
Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (entry point):
    Task "Message"
    Task "Message"
Target "BeforeBuild" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
Target "BuildOnlySettings" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
Target "GetFrameworkPaths" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.NETFramework.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "PrepareForBuild" depends on it):
Target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "PrepareForBuild" depends on it):
Target "PrepareForBuild" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
    Task "FindAppConfigFile"
    Task "MakeDir"
Target "BeforeResolveReferences" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):
Target "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "ResolveProjectReferences" depends on it):
Target "ResolveProjectReferences" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):
Target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):
    Task "ResolveAssemblyReference"
        A TargetFramework profile exclusion list will be generated.
Target "AfterResolveReferences" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):
Target "ResolveReferences" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
Target "AfterMarkupCompilePass1" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFX.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "PrepareResources" depends on it):
Target "FileClassification" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFX.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "PrepareResources" depends on it):
Target "AssignTargetPaths" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "PrepareResourceNames" depends on it):
    Task "AssignTargetPath"
    Task "AssignTargetPath"
    Task "AssignTargetPath"
    Task "AssignTargetPath"
Target "SplitResourcesByCulture" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "PrepareResourceNames" depends on it):
    Task "AssignCulture"
Target "CreateCustomManifestResourceNames" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "PrepareResourceNames" depends on it):
Target "PrepareResourceNames" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "PrepareResources" depends on it):
Target "BeforeResGen" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "ResGen" depends on it):
Target "CoreResGen" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "ResGen" depends on it):
Target "AfterResGen" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "ResGen" depends on it):
Target "ResGen" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "PrepareResources" depends on it):
Target "PrepareRdlFiles" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CompileRdlFiles" depends on it):
Target "CompileRdlFiles" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "PrepareResources" depends on it):
Target "PrepareResources" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
Target "_SetEmbeddedWin32ManifestProperties" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "SetWin32ManifestProperties" depends on it):
    Task "GetFrameworkPath"
Target "SetWin32ManifestProperties" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "Compile" depends on it):
Target "_GenerateCompileInputs" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "Compile" depends on it):
Target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "BeforeCompile" depends on it):
    Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target "BeforeCompile" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "Compile" depends on it):
Target "DesignTimeXamlMarkupCompilation" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CoreCompile" depends on it):
Target "DesignTimeMarkupCompilation" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFX.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CoreCompile" depends on it):
Target "CoreCompile" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "Compile" depends on it):
    Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target "AfterCompile" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "Compile" depends on it):
Target "AfterCompileWinFX" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFX.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "_AfterCompileWinFXInternal" depends on it):
Target "_AfterCompileWinFXInternal" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFX.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "Compile" depends on it):
Target "Compile" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
Target "_GenerateSatelliteAssemblyInputs" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CreateSatelliteAssemblies" depends on it):
Target "CreateSatelliteAssemblies" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
Target "GetTargetPath" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
Target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "_CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory" depends on it):
    Task "AssignTargetPath"
Target "_CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" depends on it):
Target "_CheckForCompileOutputs" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" depends on it):
Target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "PrepareForRun" depends on it):
    Task "Copy"
    Task "Message"
        test -> D:\F#\test\test\bin\Release\test.exe
    Task "Copy"
    Task "Copy"
Target "PrepareForRun" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
Target "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "IncrementalClean" depends on it):
    Task "ReadLinesFromFile"
    Task "ConvertToAbsolutePath"
    Task "FindUnderPath"
    Task "FindUnderPath"
    Task "FindUnderPath"
    Task "RemoveDuplicates"
Target "IncrementalClean" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
    Task "FindUnderPath"
    Task "FindUnderPath"
    Task "Delete"
    Task "RemoveDuplicates"
Target "CoreBuild" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
Target "AfterBuild" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
Target "Build" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\F#\test\test\test.fsproj" (entry point):
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

This doesn't happen in C# or C++. Anyone have a solution?

Edit:

After setting build verbosity to minimal this was the result:

```
------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Release x86 ------
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsc.exe -o:obj\x86\Release\test.exe --debug:pdbonly --noframework --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Release\test.XML --optimize+ --platform:x86 -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Numerics.dll" --target:exe --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors "D:\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client.AssemblyAttributes.fs" Program.fs 
        test -> D:\F#\test\test\bin\Release\test.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

When setting to quiet, there's no mess. That is a solution, but it's kind of hacky isn't it?

Comment: What is your [MSBuild project build output verbosity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyhcc7zc.aspx) VS setting set to?

Comment: It was set to normal. I changed it to minimal and then quiet. The output from those are in the original post now.

Comment: It's set to minimal by default, so it's not really hacky to set it _back_ to minimal. :-P

Comment: Are you sure it's set to minimal by default? I've recently done a /resetsettings and I definitely haven't changed that setting since then. But besides that, is the output in my edit what I should expect for a minimal build in F#?

Comment: @user239201 : Having just reinstalled Windows+VS this weekend, I can confirm that 'Minimal' is the default setting on a clean installation, unless it varies by environment settings template (I use 'general development settings' rather than a language-specific template).

Comment: Is that the output I should expect for minimal verbosity?

Comment: It is Minimal by default in VS.  There may be discrepencies among project systems at higher verbosities, but you typically want Minimal, and your final 'edit' is the expected.

Comment: Thank you Brian. (Why the scare quotes on edit?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Reposting from comment)

Your [MSBuild project build output verbosity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyhcc7zc.aspx) VS setting was apparently changed away from its default value of 'Minimal'. If you don't like the more verbose output, changing it back to 'Minimal' is the most appropriate solution.